# Can't create an app on Xamarin with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to lean a little with Xamarin, and while trying to create an Blank App it appears this error in the image:

[image: Visual Studio Error]

I've already tried to repair the installation, already tried to change the .NET Framework in the project, tried to install the packages and when I do, this happens

[image: Error]

Could someone please help me fix this?
Sorry if i'm making some rookie mistake, I'm really new at this.
Thanks!

Comment: Never saw this one so far, but have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling Visual Studio? Do you only have this issues with NuGet when you create Xamarin Apps? It further seems to be related to UWP and not Xamarin.Android or Xamarin.iOS. Are you running Windows 10?

Comment: Yes, I've already tried to reinstall VS and I am using Windows 10

Comment: Sorry to hear you are still in the same situation... And this happens with any Xamarin project e.g. Android? Antoher thing you could try is to delete your local NuGet cache http://lastexitcode.com/projects/NuGet/FileLocations/

Answer (score 0):

That's odd. It is trying to install version `5.0.1-beta-23516` of `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform`. On my end it installs version `5.0.0` and that works seamlessly. What version of Xamarin are you on? Can you try using the latest stable version of Xamarin for VS? In Visual Studio, navigate to menu `Tools->Options` and scroll down to expand the `Xamarin` section and select `Other`. Choose `Stable` from the drop down menu and click `Check Now`. If updates to that channel are available, you will get a dialog to download and install the updates. Make sure `Stable` is also selected in the drop down in that dialog.